# How to fix issues with React app peer dependencies- tried many online solutions but don't understand the issue

Tags: reactjs, heroku, dependencies, package.json

Making my first ever React app, which has run fine with no errors. When I went to deploy on Heroku there was a ton of peer dependency issues.

As per other stack overflow posts, I've tried npm install peer deps, clearing the cache, and changing different versions of dependencies. I'm lost now on how to fix this.

Here's my message from Heroku when trying to deploy:

-----> Installing binaries

```
   engines.node (package.json):  >=16.15.1

   engines.npm (package.json):   >=8.11.0

   

   Resolving node version >=16.15.1...

   Downloading and installing node 18.7.0...

   Bootstrapping npm >=8.11.0 (replacing 8.15.0)...

   npm 8.18.0 installed
```

-----> Installing dependencies

```
   Installing node modules

   npm ERR! code ERESOLVE

   npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve

   npm ERR! 

   npm ERR! While resolving: react-dropdown@1.10.0

   npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0

   npm ERR! node_modules/react

   npm ERR!   react@"^18.0.0" from the root project

   npm ERR!   peer react@">=17.0.2" from @devexpress/dx-react-core@3.0.4

   npm ERR!   node_modules/@devexpress/dx-react-core

   npm ERR!     @devexpress/dx-react-core@"^3.0.4" from the root project

   npm ERR!     peer @devexpress/dx-react-core@"3.0.4" from @devexpress/dx-react-scheduler@3.0.4

   npm ERR!     node_modules/@devexpress/dx-react-scheduler

   npm ERR!       @devexpress/dx-react-scheduler@"^3.0.4" from the root project

   npm ERR!       1 more (@devexpress/dx-react-scheduler-material-ui)

   npm ERR!     1 more (@devexpress/dx-react-scheduler-material-ui)

   npm ERR!   34 more (@devexpress/dx-react-scheduler, ...)

   npm ERR! 

   npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:

   npm ERR! peer react@"^0.14.7 || ^15.0.0-0 || ^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0" from react-dropdown@1.10.0

   npm ERR! node_modules/react-dropdown

   npm ERR!   react-dropdown@"^1.10.0" from the root project

   npm ERR! 

   npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@17.0.2

   npm ERR! node_modules/react

   npm ERR!   peer react@"^0.14.7 || ^15.0.0-0 || ^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0" from react-dropdown@1.10.0

   npm ERR!   node_modules/react-dropdown

   npm ERR!     react-dropdown@"^1.10.0" from the root project

   npm ERR! 

   npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry

   npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps

   npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

   npm ERR! 

   npm ERR! See /tmp/npmcache.a96D7/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

   

   npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

   npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.a96D7/_logs/2022-08-20T01_29_57_818Z-debug-0.log
```

-----> Build failed

And here's my package.json:

```
"engines": {
    "npm": ">=8.11.0",
    "node": ">=16.15.1"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@devexpress/dx-core": "^3.0.4",
    "@devexpress/dx-react-core": "^3.0.4",
    "@devexpress/dx-react-scheduler": "^3.0.4",
    "@devexpress/dx-react-scheduler-material-ui": "^3.0.4",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.1.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.1.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.1.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.1.2",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0", 
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.8.4",
    "@mui/material": "^5.10.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
    "@types/jest": "^28.1.7",
    "@types/node": "^18.7.7",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.17",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.0",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "node-sass": "^7.0.1",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "prettierrc": "^0.0.0",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.5.0",
    "react-countdown": "^2.3.2",
    "react-dark-mode-toggle": "^0.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dropdown": "^1.10.0",
    "react-media-hook": "^0.4.9",
    "react-responsive": "^9.0.0-beta.10",
    "react-reveal": "^1.2.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-router-hash-link": "^2.4.3",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-typed": "^1.2.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5",
    "typed.js": "^2.0.12",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4",
    "use-dark-mode": "^2.3.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
```

Sorry for the long post- out of ideas so hoping someone knows what's up!

Answer (score 1):

Crate a .npmrc in your root directory of the project and put either of these options in the file and try again..

```
 force=true
 legacy-peer-deps=true
```

Comment: setting `legacy-peer-deps` to true did the trick